# How can I convert each key:value pair in a dictionary to flat rows in a 2D array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
dct = {'F': [0, 0, 0, 1], 'T': [0, 3, 0, 4], 'B': [1, 1, 0, 1], 'K': [2, 2, 0, 1], 'J': [2, 4, 0, 2], 'Bxx': [4, 4, 0, 1]}
```

I'd like to convert it to the following 2D array:

```
ultimate_list = [['F', 0, 0, 0, 1], ['T', 0, 3, 0, 4], ['B', 1, 1, 0, 1], ['K', 2, 2, 0, 1], ['J', 2, 4, 0, 2], ['Bxx', 4, 4, 0, 1]]
```

So far I've done the following, which doesn't quite get me the output I'm looking for:

```
final_list = []

for k, v in dct.items():
    final_list.append([k, v])


flat_list = []
for sublist in final_list:
    for item in sublist:
        flat_list.append(item)

print(flat_list)
```

Which outputs this:

```
flat_list = ['F', [0, 0, 0, 1], 'T', [0, 3, 0, 4], 'B', [1, 1, 0, 1], 'K', [2, 2, 0, 1], 'J', [2, 4, 0, 2], 'Bxx', [4, 4, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: @coldspeed Sorry, and thank you. I think it's fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your existing code is the line `final_list.append([k, v])`, you're appending a list containing `k` and `v`, which is another list. Here's where you should've done the unpacking to flatten them into a single 1D list, i.e.,

```
for k, v in dct.items():
    final_list.append([k, *v])
```

However, you can shorten your code using a list comprehension. Older versions of python allow you to do

```
>>> [[k] + [v] for k, v in dct.items()]
```

On later versions of python (3.6+) which support starred assignments in lists, you can now do

```
>>> [[k, *v] for k, v in dct.items()]
```

```
[['F', 0, 0, 0, 1],
 ['T', 0, 3, 0, 4],
 ['B', 1, 1, 0, 1],
 ['K', 2, 2, 0, 1],
 ['J', 2, 4, 0, 2],
 ['Bxx', 4, 4, 0, 1]]
```

Note that the order of the result is the same as the dictionary ordering on python3.6+ only (dictionaries are not ordered on older versions).

Answer (score 2):

Just change the below statement

```
final_list.append([k, v])
```

to

```
final_list.append([k] + v)
```

And remove the code that follows the above statement except the last **print** statement. You're done.

I have modified your code as follows.

```
dct = {'F': [0, 0, 0, 1], 'T': [0, 3, 0, 4], 'B': [1, 1, 0, 1], 'K': [2, 2, 0, 1], 'J': [2, 4, 0, 2], 'Bxx': [4, 4, 0, 1]}

final_list = []

for k, v in dct.items():
    final_list.append([k] + v)

print(final_list)
```

» Output

```
[['B', 1, 1, 0, 1], ['F', 0, 0, 0, 1], ['T', 0, 3, 0, 4], ['J', 2, 4, 0, 2], ['Bxx', 4, 4, 0, 1], ['K', 2, 2, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert k to a list , then you can just add it to v (which is already a list). Eg. [1] + [2] = [1,2]

```
[[k] + v for k, v in dct.items()]
```